Looping through Folder and sub-folders for .xlsx where filename contains string
I am trying to develop a tool to help my department prioritize their work based on sales order (SO) due dates. Unfortunately, we do not currently have an ERP system that ties all this data together for me to easily query the data. My work around is to develop an excel workbook that lists all the currently open sales orders along with their due dates. This part of the code is working fine.
The part that I am stuck on is being able to loop through a top level folder to open a specific SO .xlsx file contained inside a sub folder, copy specific values onto my master workbook, then move to the next row which contains a different SO and repeat.
Below is my current code, which is mostly pieced together from other posts. LoopAllSubFolders returns only the first value. I am pretty sure the issue is the For loop in lines 50-54, but i am not familiar enough with loops to know how to best amend this code.
Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)

Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim targetSO As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim j As Integer

'j = 0
'Set rng = Range("A1")
'MsgBox (j)
'targetSO = rng.Value

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
    fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

        While Len(fileName) <> 0
            If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then
                    fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName
 
                    If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                        ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
                        folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
                        numFolders = numFolders + 1
                    Else
                        'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
                        'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
                        If InStr(1, fileName, Cells(j + 1, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) <> 0 And InStr(1, fullFilePath, ".xlsx", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                            Debug.Print fullFilePath
                        End If
                    End If
            End If
                fileName = Dir()
        Wend
    For i = 0 To numFolders - 1
'       j = j + 1
        LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)
 
    Next i
'Next rng

End Sub


There are only 45 lines code in your post. What's the code of ines 50-54 ?

My apologies. I trimmed a helper sub which calls this sub and another sub which writes the data in the workbook. They both work correctly. I meant to highlight the "For i..."
